# Pagination not working in opencart when SEO enabled

Tags: php, pagination, seo, opencart

Hi I am using Opencart for one of my sites, but I have realized that when I turn SEO Keywords on, the pagination isn't working.  When SEO is off it is working fine.

Is there anyone that knows why this is happening.

I have tried to find answers on the opencart forum but no luck and also I can't find anything on stack overflow...

Here is the code for my htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Prevent Directoy listing Options -Indexes
# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
     Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here is a link to one of he pages

```
http://pubstuff.co.za/Bar/Ashtrays
```

I can see the pagination code on the category.php page

```
$pagination = new Pagination();
        $pagination->total = $product_total;
        $pagination->page = $page;
        $pagination->limit = $limit;
        $pagination->text = $this->language->get('text_pagination');
        $pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&page={page}');
```

It is trying to call the 'link' or url still as the path to the correct item, but I have no idea of how to change this to call the URL for the newly rendered SEO friendly URL

Could someone please help.

Comment: By *newly rendered SEO friendly URL* You mean You have installed some SEO extension? Because with using only `seo_keyword` fields and the default OpenCart's SEO functionality this is working fine...

Comment: It is just the standard seo keyword function of opencert...

Answer (score 0):

In the link you give there is not enough products to cause pagination. You will not get pagination until the number of products exceeds the limit of 25 at least.

On http://pubstuff.co.za/Gifts-and-novelties/Other-gifts this is the case - 87 items, however, when I select a listing limit of 25 the page automatically reloads with the 100 product limit so I cannot confirm this as in error. As shadyyx comments above this is fine with the default SEO so maybe something in your theme is causing the error.

Comment: Hi Sorry I have changed the limit in the mean while to show upto 100 items

Comment: I can understand that. Do you have a staging server where you can show its function as described? You shouldn't need to modify the code - opencart resolves the regular path to the SEO path. Have you renamed htaccess? And is it allowed on your server? Do you have access to your php settings or is it shared hosting?  Check in httpd.conf that OverideAllowed is set to All (the default is none)

Comment: So the SEO URL is working but not pagination? Sorry some of the suggestions above were to resolve SEO URL not working. You may want to move to chat to resolve this.